# Getting NYtimes articles from twitter and URL lengthening

Tags: python, curl, twitter, url-shortener

I am trying to collect tweets which have links to New York times articles in them. The links are generally shortened to http://t.co.xxxxx. I found that if I use 'nytimes' as filter in my track parameter it is getting the links. I was wondering is there any solid way of achieveing the same.

Also, i want to lengthen the t.co url. I tried some APIs like ExpandURL, Unshorten.me and expandurl does not lengthen t.co and unshorten.me 's API is having some problems with them.

Is there anyone who as other sources? Is there any other way to get the lengthened url withour API?.I want it using Python

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, I believe you're trying to retrieve the actual URL which was shortened by Twitter. This can be done with a python library like requests.

Code:

```
>>> import requests
>>> resp = requests.get('http://t.co/tWsuSJ166S')
>>> resp.url
u'http://www.engadget.com/2015/04/04/microsoft-project-spartan-do-not-track/?ncid=rss_truncated'
```

Hope that helps.